# add package and bootstrap to prerequisites visual studio 2017 sql express 2016

Tags: c#, deployment, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-express, prerequisites

I cannot find sql express 2016 in prerequisites list items in my visual studio 2017. My application database is built on sql express 2016 and it should be included in the prerequisites. How can i include it's package inside visual  studio and show it to be selected in the list items please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to `Individual components` tab, you can select `SQL Server Express 2016 LocalDB` under `Cloud, database, and server`.

[image]

After that, follow the instructions on the following [GitHub repository](https://github.com/igormf/SqlLocalDB2016-Bootstrapper).

Comment: It is there and ticked but it is not appearing in the prerequisites nor in the bootstrap packages in visual studio -  . Cliubotariu Florin

Comment: Can you tell us more exactly what you expected to see in Visual Studio but you dont?

Comment: Project>properties> publish btn> prerequisites btn> showing the list items of the prerequisites where i need to tick the needed i.e dot net frame works, crystal reports ... etc to make my application installed in clients machines smoothly , i cannot see sql express 2016 all i can see is sql server express 2012 while i need 2016. this is my problem

Comment: Thanks but not sure if you understand my query. first i am looking for sql express not localdb express, second even though what you are showing me does not help in creating the package because i don't see xml files in the package only msi which i have no problem in locating msi for both local and sql express but how to package it then show it in the prerequisites is my problem?

Comment: I owe you an apology Ciubotariu Florin, it worked fine thanks alot. however, remaining the package of sql express not local. can you help with that?

Comment: @aim, I do not have exactly experience in this but can you take a look over  those 3 links? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/creating-bootstrapper-packages?view=vs-2019 ,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-install-prerequisites-with-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2019 , https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a8a1bc82-1cde-433f-a0c7-df5aee0faf31/how-to-set-the-setup-info-of-sql-server-express-prerequisite?forum=winformssetup